# How can I remove duplicates from an input file and write duplicates to a file without using XSUM in JCL?

Tags: mainframe, syncsort

How to remove duplicate file and write duplicate into file without using 'ICETOOL'

I tried this code it's working fine. But I Can't use ICETOOL. How to do this without XSUM

```
    //SORTXSUM DD DSN=datasetname,
    //           DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),UNIT=SYSDA,
    //            SPACE=(CYL,(1,4),RLSE),
    //            DCB=(RECFM=FBM,LERCL=80,BLKSIZE=800)

    //SYSIN DD *

    SORT FIELDS=(1,3,CH,A)
    SUM FIELDS=NONE,XSUM

    /*
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using SyncSORT. SyncSORT provide the undocumented SyncTOOL which is to provide the functionality of DFSORT's ICETOOL. When installed at sites, SyncTOOL is often Aliased to ICETOOL to ease migration of the JCL.

SyncSORT mainly has the same functionality as DFSORT. One of the extras, however, that SyncSORT has is `XSUM`. `XSUM` is a `SORT` function which writes the duplicate records which would otherwise be omitted by a `SUM` statement to a specific `DDNAME`.

SyncTOOL has a number of operators for combining SORT functionality and providing high-level extensions to that functionality. To find out what they are, the only documentation you can look at is DFSORT's, which is IBM's original product with which SyncSORT competes.

If you look at `Chapter 7` of the `DFSORT Application Programming Guide` you will find out about `ICETOOL`. Most of the functionality of ICETOOL is provided by SyncTOOL, depending on how up-to-date your SyncTOOL is.

`XSUM` belongs to SORT. SyncTOOL/ICETOOL are not SORT. `XSUM` is not part of SyncTOOL/ICETOOL.

You are not using ICETOOL. The example you have shown is using SORT. You are not using ICETOOL.

You have code that works for you (although you failed to paste it here correctly) which uses `EXEC PGM=SORT` and supplies `XSUM` on one of the control cards.

You have not used PGM=ICETOOL, and if you did, you would not have been able to use `XSUM` on `SYSIN` (you would have had to use `TOOLIN` for ICETOOL/SyncTOOL, and could only specify SORT statements, where allowed by the syntax, in `xxxxCNTL` files, which you haven't used.

You are good to go, and there is no question to answer.

Further from the comments before they are removed, you should not code DCB or any of its sub-parameters on an output file from SORT. SORT will supply the correct ones for you. You must not have blank cards in your JCL, this will generate a `//SYSIN DD *` which at best will cause you confusion. `SORT` and `SUM` must be preceded by at least one blank.